# Access HttpContextAccessor from Helper Class in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to access JwtHelper from ExceptionHelper. But problem is ExceptionHelper must be static. And so, we can't create constructor and not access jwtHelper Method. How can I achieve access jwHelper from ExcewptionHelper.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Run(async context =>
     {
         var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

         context.Response.AddApplicationError(error);
         await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
     }));

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

ExceptionHelper.cs

```
    public static class ExceptionHelper
    {
        public static async Task AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response)
        {
            Log log = new Log();
            log.UserId = jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken(token, "UserId");??????
            //in this line I can't access jwtHelper.
        }
    }
```

JwtHelper.cs

```
 public class JwtHelper : IJwtHelper
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public JwtHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string GetValueFromToken(string stream, string propertyName)
        {
            var jwt = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokens = handler.ReadToken(stream.Replace("Bearer ", "")) as JwtSecurityToken;
            return tokens.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == propertyName).Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `How, I can do this?` Inject `JwtHelper` in wherever you need it.

Comment: Is `JwtHelper` registered in your DI container? Perhaps attach your startup class so we can see your registrations.

Comment: JwtHelper hasn't got interface. That is only class. This code is giving error with this state. @mjwills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would register `JwtHelper` with a Interface known as `IJwtHelper`.
It would look like this then

```
public class JwtHelper : IJwtHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public JwtHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public  string GetValueFromToken(string propertyName)
    {
        var jwt= httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        // I can't access httpContextAccessor in this line.

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokens = handler.ReadToken(jwt) as JwtSecurityToken;
        return tokens.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == propertyName).Value;
    }
}

public interface IJwtHelper
{
    string GetValueFromToken(string propertyName);
}
```

In my `startup.cs` class I would then do

```
 services.AddSingleton<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
```

And then when you want to access your helper I would inject `IJwtHelper`

```
  private IJwtHelper _jwtHelper;
  public SomeConstructerOnClass(IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
    {
        _jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
    }
 public void SomeMethod(string property) {
    var token = _jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken(property);
    //Do something with token
    }
```

where `_jwtHelper` is field of type `IJwtHelper`.

You will then be able to use `GetValueFromToken` quite fine anywhere you inject `IJwtHelper`

**UPDATE**

Your problem is that  ExceptionHandler is Static , implement an interface and add it to container

```
  public class ExceptionHelper : IExceptionHelper
{
  private IJwtHelper _jwtHelper;
  public ExceptionHelper(IJwtHelper jwtHelper)
{
    _jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
}
    public async Task AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response)
    {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.UserId = _jwtHelper.GetValueFromToken(token, "UserId");??????

    }
}
public interface IExceptionHelper
{
Task AddApplicationError( HttpResponse response);
 }
```

Then

```
 services.AddSingleton<IExceptionHelper, ExceptionHelper>();
```

Now You will be able to inject it into your `Configure` method like so

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IExceptionHelper exceptionHelper)
{
 app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.Run(async context =>
 {
     var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
     //Resolved and available!
     exceptionHelper.AddApplicationError(error);
     await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
 }));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
```

}

If you follow me advice above from my initial response and my update everything should be fine and registered nicely in your container :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, reason of not using Dependency injection is "SomeConstructerOnClass" has static class. So, i can't access JwtHelper from method in SomeConstructerOnClass. I edited my question. Can you check my question again? @cl0ud

Comment: @HasanOzdemir i dont see how you are gonna get around this without using DI , `IHttpContextAccessor` is part of the DI container hence why the implementing class will require to be a part of the container aswell.  Is `JwtHelper` registered ?

Comment: In your code, "SomeMethod" is not static method. But in my new edited question, "AddAuditLog" method is static. This is the reason of problem. "AddAuditLog" method must be static. But I can't access jwtHelper from static method. @cl0ud5. So, I'm looking for solution to this problem.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Im unsure how your code interacts with other classes, if you provide the full flow for me from start to finish I can perhaps help you restructure it to help you . Im feeling the issue is that you are wanting to combine non registered classes with registered classes from a static context which is why you are running into problems.

Comment: Thanks a Iot again @cl0ud5. You're so tired because of me. I completely remove and rewrite the question with start to finish. Can you check please?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir ok we are getting somewhere , Can you show me where you call `AddApplicationError` on `ExceptionHelper`

Comment: AddAplicationError called from Startup.cs (in "configure" method) @cl0ud5

Comment: @HasanOzdemir thank you , I will update my answer now

Comment: Thanks a lot @cl0ud5. I didn't know injecting to startup. This is, what I was looking for. It solved my problem.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir no problem happy to help ! Next time provide the full flow of what you are trying to achieve , DI containers are tricky thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to instantiate the JwtHelper class in order to access the instance variable (httpContextAccessor) from another class. Static methods, like GetValueFromToken, cannot access instance variables.

Comment: Did you mean that, I create IJwtHelper interface and then inject it when i need jwthelper. Is it true? @Sean